# Validating a string pattern in regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following string:

```
  /xyz/10.2005/abc.d10.1/example
```

Here what I want to validate is, there should not be a space after "/xyz/".

Like It should not accept if the string is:

```
  /xyz/ 10.2005/abc.d10.1/example
```

But it should accept if the string is:

```
  10.2005/abc.d10.1/example
```

How can I modify the following regex to validate the above thing??

```
  REGEX- "^\\S*((10(\\.\\d+)+)\\/([^\\/]+)(\\/\\d+[\\.+[a-zA-Z\\d]]*)?)"
```

Could someone help me??

Comment: Is this Java regex? The double escapes look familiar. If so, mark it as such. Otherwise state the regex implementation you are using.

Comment: No It's javascript regex. Not sure if the regex is correct though

Comment: what conditions should met this regex? (except the mentioned space)

Comment: @BoristheSpider—the quotes make me think this is a a string to be passed to the RegExp constructor. As a literal: `/^\S*((10(\.\d+)+)\/([^\/]+)(\/\d+[\.+[a-zA-Z\d]]*)?)/`.

Comment: so you want it to match if the pattern following the one preceding it has a space? it should accept if the string is without the xyz or the space? i'm confused.

Comment: Some more examples of strings that you want to validate could help describing your problem, especially since your regex [is matching correctly](http://regex101.com/r/xS9wB5).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually you need to make it a `lazy` regex

just change it to this

```
^\\S*?((10(\\.\\d+)+)\\/([^\\/]+)(\\/\\d+[\\.+[a-zA-Z\\d]]*)?).*
```

see those `?` and `.*` at the end

demo here : http://regex101.com/r/zJ7yX8

Comment: because when you do `.*` it will first select the full text and then start matching by vomiting characters one by one. Thus it matches the `10.1` before `10.2005` because for a greedy one `10.1` comes before

Comment: OK, granted. I am not sure if this is the OPs problem, but I see now even more problems with his regex.

Answer (score 1):

This may be what you are looking for (it's a literal, you can convert it to a string if you really need to use the RegExp constructor):

```
var re = /^(\/\w+\/10|\s*10)\.\d+\/\w+\.\w\d+\.\d\/\w{7}/;

var s = '/xyz/10.2005/abc.d10.1/example';
var t = '/xyz/ 10.2005/abc.d10.1/example';
var u = ' 10.2005/abc.d10.1/example';

console.log(
            's:' + re.test(s) + '\n' +   // true
            't:' + re.test(t) + '\n' +   // false
            'u:' + re.test(u) + '\n'     // true
);
```

It does more than just validate the space after the /xyz/ part, I hope the rest is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a long RegEx:

```
/(?:\/[a-z]+\/)?\10\.\d{4}\/[a-z]{3}\.[a-z]\d{2}\.\d\/[a-z]{7}/i

//  or the following if you don't want exact occurrences

/(?:\/[a-z]+\/)?10\.\d+\/[a-z]+\.[a-z]\d+\.\d\/[a-z]+/i
```

Matches:

```
/xyz/10.2005/abc.d10.1/example

10.2005/abc.d10.1/example
```

`?:` makes the group *non-capturing*.
The `?` after the bracket-end symbolize it is optional.
Next is fairly simple RegEx.

For more explanation, [here's a demo](http://regex101.com/r/qN9dJ2)